# Characters that can follow a $variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I am looking for a list of characters that can follow a $variable in PHP. Original task is to go through a file and replace every instance of a variable with different text. But if a file contained `$cat` and `$cat2` and I simply replaced every instance of `$cat` with `$dog`, I'd have `$dog2` and could not replace `$cat2` with `$dog3` if I wanted.

Possible solution: order by length and do longest variables first?

The most obvious ones: `),.&+-/*:;%?=[<>!|`

For example, you could have a PHP file that had lines like this:

```
$var = explode($sep, $text);
```

As you can see, variables are followed by " ", "," and ")" in that line.
What other ones am I missing? Thanks for help, guys.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: what...? try to be more clear

Comment: What is the original task?

Comment: Also #, (white space/tab/line feed/etc), %, :, ?, [, <, >,= -- There's probably more.

Comment: Hi Steve, the possibilities are almost endless if you do it this way. As in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793868/get-all-variables-from-a-php-file-without-initializing-it) you should parse the variables by a prescribed format (e.g. I think it's letters, underscores and numbers without having a number as the first character that is OK) so you have a better way of working out where a variable ends.

Comment: Guys, what if we wait for the OP to explain the original task? We all know that the question as it is asked at the moment is useless.

Comment: @scrowler thanks for replying to all my posts, haha.
Is it possible that (using info from my other question)
that this would work? 

`Possible solution: order by length and do longest variables first?`

Comment: If you want to modify some valid php code - you may use [tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) (but it all still is weird anyway)

Comment: Why you do not what to use IDE for renaming?

Comment: @Steve [here's a pretty good regex](http://regex101.com/r/dP2nI0/4) to match all variables in a script, including variables by reference and excluding invalid variable names like ones that start with numbers

Comment: don'y try to identify the character after the varible, instead, identify the variable itself. use some regexp like this  [$][a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*

Comment: @scrowler i am not 100% sure that he would want &$a with your regexp

Comment: Php trolls anyone who thinks they know what characters are in a variable. `${'->'} = 3;` Now you have a variable named `${'->'}`. Just [use the built-in tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php).

Comment: True, probably replace the variable and leave the reference where it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implemented it just for fun (even though I still don't understand why you need that):

```
$code = '<?php

$cat = "foo";
$cat2 = "bar";
$dog = "baz";

';

$replace = array(
    'cat' => 'dog',
    'cat2' => 'not_dog',
    'dog' => 'cat',
);

$tokens = token_get_all($code);

$newCode = '';

foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if (is_array($token)) {
        if ($token[0] == T_VARIABLE) {
            $variableName = substr($token[1], 1);
            if (array_key_exists($variableName, $replace)) {
                $token[1] = sprintf('$%s', $replace[$variableName]);
            }
        }

        $part = $token[1];
    } else {
        $part = $token;
    }

    $newCode .= $part;
}

echo $newCode;
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/WUlRdo

Comment: @Loz Cherone ツ: this one is terrible actually: the worst variable names, 3 nested `if`s, ohh

Comment: +1 so awful I upvoted it. (Because all I really wanted out of life was to see someone use `token_get_all` instead of a regex.) ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual -

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

So there you go - if you want to replace all instance of a variable, you just negate the second character class in that regular expression.

```
preg_replace('/\$replaceMe([^a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]|$)/', '$bar', $myCode);
```

Comment: This code will not only replace variables, but also any strings that look like variables. Eg: `'$foo'`

Comment: And would not replace ${'foo'}

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the ones you posted:

- Whitespace and new lines
- `(` as in: `$obj = new $variableClassName()`

  - See [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)
- `\` to escape characters after a variable inside [double quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), like `"\"$variable\""`
- `#` for line comments, as in `$variable#comment`